# PendingServicerouting trigger

Tags: before-trigger, omnichannel

I have a requirement to route cases based on case creation date instead of when the case enters the queue. I am planning on creating a trigger on pendingservicerouting before insert to update CustomRequestedDateTime. Any help is appreciated on how this requirement can be achieved for queue based routing

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm

> When you use PendingServiceRouting objects for queue-based routing,
>   the PendingServiceRouting objects don’t invoke triggers before or
>   after insert, or any action (trigger, workflow rule, validation) that
>   could interfere with the creation of the PendingServiceRouting object.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger on the PendingServiceRouting object as documentation saying will **not be invoked**. You would need to create a Trigger or a Flow on a Case object to trigger, you can use either before or after update. Then query PendingServiceRouting where the WorkItemId equals triggered case Id.
After that you would modify the CustomRequestedDateTime to be Case CreatedDate and save the record.

Something like below:

```
  List<PendingServiceRouting> lstPendingServiceRouting = new List<PendingServiceRouting>();
        lstPendingServiceRouting = [SELECT Id, CustomRequestedDatetime, WorkItemId FROM PendingServiceRouting Where WorkItemId IN :caseIds AND CustomRequestedDatetime = null];
        for(PendingServiceRouting w : lstPendingServiceRouting) {     
            w.CustomRequestedDatetime = mapOfCaseIdToCase.get(w.WorkItemId).CreatedDate;
            lstPendingWorkItems.add(w);
        }

        Database.SaveResult[] saveRes = Database.update(lstPendingWorkItems, false);
    }
```